# Host name and Computer name in windows .?

Tags: windows

in programming most of the time we query about the "host name" in windows

but when we set the host name is window its called "computer name".

Is there any differences in Host Name and Computer Name.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host name is the name the computer is set to on the network, whereas computer name is the name that Windows uses locally. The host name or (domain name) is usually derived from the computer name (ie. Its the same for most situations) when you connect to a network.